# What java does if the closing of resource fails?

Tags: java, resources, try-catch, finally

In old times, where I had to use some resource, I declared it out of the try block, created it in the try block, and closed it in finally block. For the case if the closing will fail, it was put into inner try block.

```
Resource r=null;
try{
   r=new Resource();
   use(r); 
} 
catch(){
    outputAndLog(something);
}
finally{
    if(r != null){
        try{
        }
        catch(){
            outputAndLog(somethingElse);
        }
    }
}
```

Now we can use

```
try(Resource r = new Resource()){
```

java syntax. And the block finally becomes invisible for us. But what is in it? I mean, what happens, if the closing fails?

Answer (score 3):

Resource: [Link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/trywithresources-401775.html)

---

First of all, the `try-with-resources` does not actually handle any `Exceptions` (like it is done in your code by logging). Basically it *marshalls* the possibly multiple `Exceptions` thrown from the `try-catch-finally` construct into a processable object - an `Exception` containing suppressed `Exceptions`.

If the `try` block throws an `Exception`, the resource will be closed and a resulting `Exception` will be suppressed. In consequence the thrown `Exception` object will have a reference to the suppressed `Exception`.
If the `try` block does not throw an `Exception`, the resource will be closed and a resulting `Exception` will be rethrown.

Thus we can conclude that your examples are **not** equivalent:
When using `try-catch-finally` an `Exception` caused by closing after successful processing will be treated as 'just a close error', while with the `try-with-resources` statement such an `Exception` will be handled equally to an `Exception` that occurred in the actual processing.

**tl;dr**
If handling the closure of resources includes more *stuff*, a `try-with-resources` statement might produce bugs that are not encountered with good old `try-catch-finally`. An example for such *stuff* is the committing and rollbacking of a `jdbc` connection.

---

So, to finally produce some code, for

```
try(Resource resource = new Resource()){
    // other code
}
```

the exact equivalent would be:

```
{
    Resource resource = null;
    Exception exc = null;
    try {
        resource = new Resource();
        // other code
    } catch (Exception e) {
        exc = e;
        throw e;
    } finally {
        if (resource != null) {
            if (exc != null) {
                try {
                    resource.close();
                } catch (Throwable t) {
                    exc.addSuppressed(t);
                }
            } else {
                resource.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As i understand  [JLS 14.20.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3) `A resource is closed only if it initialized to a non-null value`, there should be check on `resource!=null` in finally block. Am I wrong?

Comment: You're completely right, I'll edit. I guess this is a good example of why we should use the `try-with-resources` statement: trying to reproduce it often results in bugs.

Answer (score 1):

> But what is in it?

```
try {
    Resource resource = initResource();
    Object possibleExceptionFromTry = null;
    ...
    if (stream != null) {
        if (possibleExceptionFromTry != null) {
            try {
                stream.close();
            } catch (Throwable exceptionFromClosing) {
                ((Throwable)possibleExceptionFromTry).addSuppressed(exceptionFromClosing);
            }
        } else {
            stream.close();
        }
    }
} catch (IOException exception) { ... }
```

> What happens, if the closing fails?

If everything passes well in `try`,  you will catch an exception from `Resource#close()` in `catch`. Otherwise, an exception from `try` will suppress an exception thrown from `Resource#close` and put it into an array that can be obtained by `Throwable#getSuppressed`:

```
} catch (IOException exception) {
    final Throwable[] suppressedExceptions = exception.getSuppressed();
    // exception = the exception from try
    // suppressedExceptions = the last exception (if any) is likely caused by closing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Java tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html):

> If an exception is thrown from the try block and one or more
>   exceptions are thrown from the try-with-resources statement, then
>   those exceptions thrown from the try-with-resources statement are
>   suppressed, and the exception thrown by the block is the one that is
>   thrown... You can retrieve
>   these suppressed exceptions by calling the Throwable.getSuppressed
>   method from the exception thrown by the try block.

Answer (score 0):

try-with-resources is calling implementation of method `close` from `java.lang.AutoClosable` interface.

From [JLS 14.20.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3)

> Resources are closed in the reverse order from that in which they were
>   initialized. A resource is closed only if it initialized to a non-null
>   value. An exception from the closing of one resource does not prevent
>   the closing of other resources. Such an exception is suppressed if an
>   exception was thrown previously by an initializer, the try block, or
>   the closing of a resource.

For your example `try(Resource r = new Resource())` should be this full equivalent:

```
    Resource r = null;
    Exception ex = null;
    try {
        r = new Resource();
        use(r);
    } catch (Exception e){
        ex = e;
    }
    finally {
        if (r != null) {
            try {
                r.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (ex!=null){
                    ex.addSuppressed(e);
                } else {
                    ex = e;
                }
            }
        }
        if (ex != null){
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```